# Allow Web Apps through Network Security Group

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans, azure-nsg

We have a few Web Apps that need to access database on VM that behind Network Security Group. How do we allow Web App through Network Security Group?

Comment: have you tried assigning a service endpoint? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web App will use a set of outbound Public IP addresses to reach Internet. You can get those IP address by navigating to the Properties of the Web App.

In your NSG, you can use the Source IP as the list of IP that you got from Properties blade to allow traffic to your database. Also make sure to only open the port used by the database, and nothing else.